# Реализация min / max Python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь понять реализацию функции min/max.
Мысли у меня следующие :

1. Если на вход подаётся список с числами и (len!=1) - сортировать список

   ```
   tmp.sort(key=key)
   return tmp[0]
   ```

   выбрать первый элемент(мин) или последний(макс)
2. Если на вход подаётся текст(получается что len==1) - реализую поиск меньшей/большей буквы

   ```
   min_text = args[0]
   for i in args[0]:
       if i < min_text:
           min_text = i
   return min_text
   ```
3. Но если мне на вход подается кортеж -

   ```
   [[1,2], [3, 4], [9, 0]], key=lambda x: x[1]
   ```

   то при проверке на длину, он попадает под len == 1, и не проходит реализацию.

Подскажите, видимо я пытаюсь построить велосипед, как будет правильнее реализовать такую функцию?

Comment: в сторону: "кортеж" это tuple, а у вас в примере только списки. Если у вас код работает для случая №1, то и для случая №3 он также работал бы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите повторить реализацию стандартной функции `max` (или `min`, но там почти так же, поэтому я расскажу про один `max`), то вот несколько соображений, которые нужны для этого:

- Если аргумент один, то считаем его объектом, по которому можно пройтись циклом (iterable). Такими объектами являются списки, кортежи, строки, генераторы и многое другое, так что не надо рассматривать списки отдельно от строк.
- Если аргументов два или больше, то соединяем их в один список, который автоматически iterable.
- Переменное число аргументов можно принять с помощью `*args`.

С учётом всего этого можно написать функцию примерно такую:

```
def max2(arg1, *args, key=lambda x: x):
    # arg1 — первый аргумент, args — список из второго и последующих аргументов
    if args:
        # Передали несколько аргументов — объединяем все в один список
        iterable = [arg1] + list(args)
    else:
        # Передали один аргумент — считаем, что он iterable
        iterable = arg1
    # Сначала в качестве максимума выберем первый элемент
    result = iterable[0]
    # Перебираем остальные элементы
    for item in iterable[1:]:
        if key(item) > key(result):
            result = item
    return result
```

Насколько я могу судить, она (в рамках заданной мной области применимости) соответствует стандартной реализации `max` в Python:

```
>>> max(3, 4, 5) == max2(3, 4, 5)
True  # 5
>>> max([3, 4, 5]) == max2([3, 4, 5])
True  # 5
>>> max('abc') == max2('abc')
True  # 'c'
>>> max([[1, 2], [3, 4], [9, 0]], key=lambda x: x[1]) == max2([[1, 2], [3, 4], [9, 0]], key=lambda x: x[1])
True  # [3, 4]
```

(Но в этой функции я для простоты опустил обработку пустых списков и поддержку объектов, в которым нельзя обращаться по индексу (генераторы, например), так что данная функция годится только в образовательных целях, а в реальных программах используйте обычный `max` :)

---

Вот более точная реализация (теперь уже не `max`, а `min`), но более сложная для понимания, поэтому пишу её отдельно. Чтобы поддерживать обработку iterable-объектов, придётся отказаться от обращения к нему по индексу и устанавливать первый элемент более хитро.

```
def min2(arg1, *args, default=None, key=lambda x: x):
    if args:
        # Если у нас список аргументов, то не церемонимся
        # и начинаем сразу с первого элемента
        result = arg1
        started = True
        iterable = args
    else:
        # Если у нас iterable первым аргументом, то
        # поцеремонимся и начнём в цикле for (это позволяет
        # избавиться от обращения по индексу)
        result = default
        started = False
        iterable = arg1
    # Проходимся по элементам iterable-объекта
    for item in iterable:
        if not started:
            # Если первого элемента ещё не существует,
            # то ставим его
            result = item
            started = True
            continue
        # Если предыдущий элемент существует, то сравниваем
        if key(item) < key(result):
            result = item
    return result
```

Такая функция соответствует родной реализации почти во всех известных мне случаях (кроме одного несущественного для вопроса `min([])`):

```
>>> min({5, 4, 3}) == min2({5, 4, 3})
True  # 3
>>> min([], default=-7) == min2([], default=-7)
True  # -7; только в Python 3
>>> min(abs(i) for i in range(-10,10)) == min2(abs(i) for i in range(-10,10))
True  # 0
```

Здесь, в отличие от более простой предыдущей реализации, теперь не создаётся никаких списков, а есть лишь несколько переменных, поэтому эта реализация O(1) в памяти (можно без траты оперативы обработать сколь угодно много элементов, если достать соответствующий генератор, например `range` (`xrange` в Python 2)). Цикл тут один-единственный, поэтому O(n) по шагам, что соответствует стандартной реализации (если верить комментарию jfs).

Comment: Супер! Ваша реализация работает! Однако, как быть с реализацией min(abs(i) for i in range(-10,10), появляется ошибка "TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable"?

Comment: Можно упомянуть, что стандартная реализация O(1) в памяти (не использует list())  и O(n) по шагам (не использует sort()). Учитывая заголовок вопроса, можно также показать iter + next + for -loop реализацию.

Comment: Окей, дописал более точную реализацию (но предпочёл без iter-next)

Answer (score 2):

Найти минимум/максимум можно, используя один линейный алгоритм для разных типов ввода: как для списков с числами, так и для строк, так и для списка пар итд:

```
def min_item(items, *, key=lambda x: x):
    min_, *items = items
    for item in items:
        if key(item) < key(min_):
            min_ = item
    return min_
```

Пример:

```
>>> min_item([2, 1, 3])
1
>>> min_item("aBc")
'B'
>>> min_item([[1,2], [3, 4], [9, 0]], key=lambda x: x[1])
[9, 0]
```

где [синтаксис со звёдочкой](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#rationale), используется, чтобы первый элемент из коллекции достать:

```
>>> a, *b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(a, b)
1 [2, 3]
```

`sorted(items, key=key)[0]` сработало бы для всех представленных случаев, но сортировка, основанная на сравнениях, требует [`O(n * log n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) операций, поэтому показан простой цикл как пример реализации `min()`, используя линейный (`O(n)`) алгоритм.

---

Стандартные min/max функции сложнее представленной `min_item()`:

- можно передавать несколько аргументов:

  ```
  >>> min(1, 2, 3)
  1
  ```
- если ввод пустой, то может быть возвращено значение по умолчанию:

  ```
  >>> min([], default=1)
  1
  ```
- потребляемая память не зависит от количества переданных элементов (в то время как реализация выше, использует `O(n)` дополнительной памяти—чем больше ввод, тем больше памяти требуется)
- можно оптимизировать алгоритм, чтобы избежать вызова `key()` несколько раз для одного и того же элемента.

Легко адаптировать `min_item()` функцию, чтобы она несколько аргументов поддерживала:

```
def min_item(first, *args, key=lambda x: x):
    if not args: # first is an iterable
        first, *args = first
    for arg in args:
        if key(arg) < key(first):
            first = arg
    return first
```

В этом случае, если передан один аргумент (`len(args) == 0` и поэтому `not args` ветка выполняется), то поведение идентично первому примеру. Если передано несколько позиционных аргументов, то ищется минимум среди них:

```
>>> min_item(2, 1, 3)
1
>>> min_item([2, 1, 3])
1
>>> min_item("aBc", key=str.lower)
'a'
```

Чтобы удовлетворить требования к памяти, можно использовать итераторы:

```
_sentinel = object()

def min(first, *args, key=lambda x: x, default=_sentinel):
    if not args:  # first is an iterable
        args = iter(first)
        try:
            first = next(args)
        except StopIteration: # empty
            if default is _sentinel:
                raise ValueError("min() arg is an empty sequence") from None
            return default
    elif default is not _sentinel:
        raise TypeError("Cannot specify a default for min() with multiple positional arguments")
    min_key = key(first)
    for arg in args:
        k = key(arg)
        if k < min_key:
            min_key = k
            first = arg
    return first
```

Эта функция ведёт себя как [стандартная `min()` функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).

`_sentinel` используется, чтобы определить был ли передан `default` параметр при вызове функции.

`key()` функция вызывается только один раз для каждого элемента на входе.

Эта реализация функции `min()` поддерживает произвольное (конечное) число входных элементов, не увеличивая потребляемую дополнительную память с ростом ввода.

Пример:

```
>>> min_(map(len, file)) # длина самой короткой строки в (возможно большом) файле
>>> min_(1, 2, 3)
1
>>> min_(x*x for x in range(-10, 3))
0
>>> min([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
>>> min([], default=1)
1
```

Реализация `max()` крайне похожа—достаточно `<` на `>` поменять.